# Why do I get the error “ Invalid kernel arguments” when using enqueueNDRangeKernel？

Tags: javascript, node.js, c, opencl

My current algorithm will call the `enqueueNDRangeKernel` function multiple times each time. Before calling it, I will use `enqueueWriteBuffer` to modify the value of a parameter. But the problem now is that sometimes when calling `enqueueNDRangeKernel`, there will be an "Invalid kernel arguments" error. The last occurrence was in the last month. It appeared again yesterday, which is too random. Can someone give me a solution? I checked the relevant information and said that this error is generally because the parameters of a kernel are not set, but I checked the `enqueueWriteBuffer` function and it reported no errors. 
The parameters I passed to the GPU are:

```
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 0, "double*", d_X);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 1, "double*", d_A);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 2, "int*", d_A_INDIEX);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 3, "int*", d_A_INDICE);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 4, "double*", d_CONSTANTS);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 5, "int*", d_ourpartitions);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 6, "int*", d_INDIEX);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 7, "int*", d_hasGreater);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 8, "int", xnum);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 9, "int", ynum);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 10, "int", n);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 11, "int", iterations);
cl.setKernelArg(kernel, 12, "double", error);
```

The way I call enqueueNDRangeKernel is as follows:

```
for (var j = 0; j <partitions.length;j++) {
    INDIEX[0] = INDICE[j];
    State = cl.enqueueWriteBuffer(queue, d_INDIEX, true, 0, intsize, INDIEX);
    if(State != 0){
        console.log("Write INDIEX error! "+ State);
    }
    var localSize = null;
    // This place sometimes gives an error: Error: Invalid kernel arguments ?? (you can look at it again)
    var globalSize=[partitions[j].length];
    State = cl.enqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1,
        null,
        globalSize,
        localSize
    );
    if(State != 0){
        console.log("enqueueNDRangeKernel error! "+ State);
    }
    cl.finish(queue);
}
```

My kernel function prototype is as follows:

```
__kernel void kernelCode(
    __global double* X,
    __global double * A,
    __global int * A_INDIEX,
    __global int * A_INDICE,
    __global double * b,
    __global int* partitions,
    __global int* INDIEX,
    __global int* hasGreater,
    const int xnum,
    const int ynum,
    const int n,
    const int iterations,
    const double error);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Ideally, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) although it sounds like the problem is intermittent, so that's likely not possible. At minimum, however, please post all the code for creating and setting your kernel arguments, the signature of your kernel function, and the enqueue function call, as well as any existing error checking you already have in place for all of those OpenCL calls.

Comment: That said, I suspect a buffer creation might occasionally be failing. Are you checking for errors there too? You could also somehow be exhausting device resources, for example by leaking OpenCL objects. Without code, we can only guess, however.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I re-edited my question and provided the corresponding information. In addition, the framework I use is [node-opencl](https://github.com/mikeseven/node-opencl), will it have anything to do with this?@pmdj

Comment: Every time an error is reported, the above console.log will not output an error, which means that enqueueWriteBuffer has not executed an error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with node-opencl, but if you're somehow encountering an error from `enqueueNDRangeKernel` but the function is not *returning* an error, that's definitely a node-opencl specific quirk. Raw OpenCL raises errors via the return value or error output parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've never used *node-opencl*, so I'm no expert on how to use it. But it looks like it handles errors differently than your code is expecting it to. Specifically, in the [implementation of the `enqueueNDRangeKernel` wrapper](https://github.com/mikeseven/node-opencl/blob/cb5abaa8ca8e2c2c3ed9bc6ac4e981a288e7a94e/src/commandqueue.cpp#L1167):

```
  CHECK_ERR(::clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
    q->getRaw(),
    k->getRaw(),
    work_dim,
    cl_work_offset.size() ? cl_work_offset.data() : nullptr,
    cl_work_global.size() ? cl_work_global.data() : nullptr,
    cl_work_local.size() ? cl_work_local.data() : nullptr,
    (cl_uint)cl_events.size(), NOCL_TO_CL_ARRAY(cl_events, NoCLEvent),
    eventPtr
  ));
  RETURN_EVENT
}
```

we can see that the underlying call to OpenCL's `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` is wrapped in a `CHECK_ERR` macro which is [defined like this](https://github.com/mikeseven/node-opencl/blob/cb5abaa8ca8e2c2c3ed9bc6ac4e981a288e7a94e/src/common.h#L50):

```
#define CHECK_ERR(ret)  { cl_int _err=(ret); \
  if ((_err) != CL_SUCCESS) { \
    return Nan::ThrowError(JS_STR(opencl::getExceptionMessage(_err))); \
  } \
}
```

`RETURN_EVENT` meanwhile is defined like this:

```cpp
#define RETURN_EVENT                                        \
  if (eventPtr) {                                           \
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(NOCL_WRAP(NoCLEvent, event)); \
  } else {                                                  \
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(JS_INT(CL_SUCCESS));          \
  }
```

This means any error is never returned via the JS wrapper function's return value, but by a thrown exception. So if my JavaScript knowledge is up to scratch, if an error is encountered during one of the CL calls, your "error handler" code will never actually run because the function is exiting early due to the thrown exception.

So I don't know what's the underlying cause of your problem, but:

- `State` will only ever be 0 (`CL_SUCCESS`) or an event object, it will never return the error.
- If you want to handle errors it looks like you need to use a `try`/`catch` construct.
- I think you will need to look in detail what is up with your kernel arguments. Clearly `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` is returning `CL_​INVALID_​KERNEL_​ARGS`.

As it's working "most of the time" I suspect buffer creation is somehow ending up going wrong, perhaps because of resource exhaustion? I don't know how node-opencl handles buffers but if it uses garbage collection in place of explicit destruction of buffers, I could imagine you might need to force a sweep after you're done with buffers. If buffers *are* explicitly created and destroyed, perhaps you're not destroying all of them?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After listening to your suggestion, I will first try to write some try/catch to catch the error, understand which parameter setting is specific and what is the error? In addition, I just watched [some discussions about node-opencl](https://github.com/mikeseven/node-opencl/pull/32), and indeed someone is reporting the problem of memory leaks.

Comment: In fact, I just got in touch with the GPU, so I just understand the general process used by OpenCL. I have also used native OpenCL to achieve the same function(C++), but I have not encountered the same type of problem. Perhaps I was running too few times at the time, and now I mainly run this code based on node-opencl(JS).